# How do you use sessions with Compojure/Ring?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm developing a web application using Compojure and I would hugely appreciate a small and complete example of storing and retrieving session data.

Many thanks in advance,
James.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example of using both Ring's functional style of working with sessions and using an external library (sandbar) to work with the session through a map style interface:

[GitHub](https://github.com/brentonashworth/sandbar-examples/blob/master/sessions/src/sandbar/examples/session_demo.clj)

If you are only interested in the Ring approach then you could replace wrap-stateful-session with wrap-session in this example and that will work.

As the author of sandbar, I prefer the map approach but both styles have their place.

Comment: Thank you Brenton :) Your sandbar package looks really good. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/brentonashworth/sandbar-examples/blob/master/sessions/src/sandbar/examples/session_demo.clj

Comment: Links are dead.